# Give a natural deduction proof of $\varphi\vdash\top$, where $\varphi$ is any formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

As in the title, the question is

> Give a natural deduction proof of $\varphi\vdash\top$, where $\varphi$ is any formula.

Could I do this proof by deriving  $\varphi \rightarrow \top$ with $ \rightarrow$-introduction rule which says that if you can derive a formula $\psi$ from a formula $\varphi$, then $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ is true. So, with this derivation I will use $\varphi$  as an assumption and derive from $\varphi$, or am I thinking wrong? I prefer hints before solution!

Comment: No, it is not :P I am going to derive $\top$ from $φ$. But I wounder if I can proof that the derivation of $\top$ from  $φ$ can be done by derive $\varphi \rightarrow \top$ instead.

Comment: Of course, if you have derived $\varphi \rightarrow \top$, then obviously assuming $\varphi$ licenses you to conclude with $\top$. But how you think to derive $\varphi \rightarrow \top$? if not using $\rightarrow$-intro from $\varphi \vdash \top$ ... And so we are back to the start.

Comment: I were thinking that I could start with the conclusion that $\varphi \rightarrow \top$ is true. Then I would use $\rightarrow-introduction$ rule to get and then use $V-elimination$ rule to get,  above this line, $\varphi V\top$ and a derivation from $\varphi$, respectively $\top$, to $\top$. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: I'm not sure about it ... You have to try to write it and see if it's right. If you assume $\varphi → ⊤$, are you sure that you are able to discharge it ?

Comment: The way I was taught, the Natural Deduction calculus had a $\top$ formation rule. That was kind of the whole use of introducing the predicate $\top$ in the first place. It might help to reference what exposition of Natural Deduction you are following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

I'll give you an answer in *Hilbert-style*, and I suggest you to try to convert it into *Natural Deduction*.

A quite "ubiquitous" axiom in *Hilbert-style* propositional logic is :

> $\vdash \psi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$.

Thus, if we can prove $\vdash \psi$, we can use *modus ponens* (i.e. $\rightarrow$-elimination) to conclude with :

> $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$.

The lesson is :

> > if we have proved a formula $\psi$, we can always add a "premise" $\varphi$ whatever to assert $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$.

Thus, the question suggests the following strategy : we have to prove : $\vdash \top$ and then use it as $\psi$ above.

---

*Proof*

*i)* $\varphi$ --- assumed

*ii)* $\bot$ --- assumed

*iii)* $\bot \vdash \bot$ --- from ii)

*iv)* $\vdash \bot \rightarrow \bot$ --- from iii) by $\rightarrow$-intro

*v)* $\vdash \lnot \bot$ --- by def of $\lnot$

*vi)* $\vdash \top$ --- abbreviation.

Thus, from i) and vi) :

> > $\varphi \vdash \top$.

Comment: Since $\top$ is a 0-ary conjuction it should have 0 formulas above the line and the formula $\top$ below it. And accordning to the same analogy, it sohuld have 0 eliminatiuon rules. Therefore we can conclude that $\top$ symbolizes the true proposition?

Comment: Are my argument enought to prove $\vdash \top$ ? @MauroALLGRANZA

Comment: thanks :) @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @Anna - Basically it's right, but in *Natural Deduction* ⊤ is not primitive; thus, there are no rules for it. But it is defined as : ¬⊥ ... and at this point we have the solution. Assume $\bot$; then $\bot \vdash \bot$. Apply $\rightarrow$-intro : $\vdash \bot \rightarrow \bot$ which, by def of $\lnot$ is : $\vdash \lnot \bot$ which we abbreviate as : $\vdash \top$.

Comment: Do you recommend any good page about these kinds of proofs?

Comment: I thnik that Wiki's page about [Natural Deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) it is not enoufìgh to learn "how it works". You need some good textbook; personally, I like : Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical ogic](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Logic-Oxford-Texts/dp/0199215626/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1411035329&sr=8-1&keywords=Ian+Chiswell+%26+Wilfrid+Hodges+Mathematical+Logic) (2007).

Comment: @Anna - You can also try with [this](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.damboeck/ps06/clemente_nat_ded.pdf) . *Note* : he states $\vdash \top$ as an allowed introduction rule ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that might be proven using explosion (X), negation introduction (¬I), contradiction introduction (⊥I) and conditional introduction (→I).

To implement this in this [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) I let $\top$ be the same as $\neg \bot$ and  $P$ is any formula corresponding to $\psi$ in the question.

[image]

A shorter proof also works using negation introduction (¬I) and conditional introduction (⊥I):

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/